# Dynamic omniauth.rb file rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, magento

I am using the omniauth-magento gem: http://rubydoc.info/gems/omniauth-magento/0.0.6/frames

Setting my omniauth.rb file in initializers as such:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :magento, "TOKEN", "SECRET", :client_options => { :authorize_path => "/su", :site => "https://store.magento.com" }     
end
```

The store needs to be dynamic though. How can I make it such OR how can I do the same thing in a controller?

Thanks!

I should mention there is another gem: https://github.com/Contiamo/omniauth-magento which allows to set dynamically but i have no clue where to put this.